# What makes the ids of new items increment automatically (asp.net core's DbContext + InMemoryDatabase)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm learning ASP.NET Core following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and I notice the following behavior of a `POST` method.

[image]

#### My question:

What specifically makes the `id` of a newly created item increment automatically? (For simplicity, I'm using in-memory database as suggested in the tutorial.)

---

*<---------The following are related code snippets, same as the code in the tutorial------------->*

#### Context and Entity:

*TodoItem.cs*

```cs
namespace TodoApi.Models 
{
    public class TodoItem 
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*TodoContext.cs*

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TodoApi.Models 
{
    public class TodoContext : DbContext 
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options) : base(options) {}

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Controller:

*TodoController.cs (`POST` method)*

```cs
namespace TodoApi.Controllers 
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoController : ControllerBase 
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;
        public TodoController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<TodoItem> Create(TodoItem item) 
        {
            _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs

*`ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs*

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of EF.

*The difference between Traditional Database and In-Memory Database is only that in In-Memory Database (IMDB, also known as a main memory database or MMDB) is a database whose data is stored in main memory to facilitate faster response times where Traditional Database does not.*

Altogether EF behavior applies to both database.

Depending on the database provider being used, values may be generated client side by EF or in the database. If the value is generated by the database, then EF may assign a temporary value when you add the entity to the context. This temporary value will then be replaced by the database generated value during SaveChanges().

If you add an entity to the context that has a value assigned to the property, then EF will attempt to insert that value rather than generating a new one.

You can set your value generation in three different ways

1) No value generation

```
public class TodoItem 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

2) Value generated on add

```
public class TodoItem 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

3) Value generated on add or update.

```
public class TodoItem 
{        
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Reference: [`Value Generation Patterns In EF Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties)

Comment: @Liutong Chen, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Glad to hear that you got what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a default what Entity Framework does. When he finds an Id or related name field he sets it as a primary key of the table. It is by default auto-incremental. If you don't want this to be done by default you can use a below attribute for an Id field:

```
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

[Read more about generated values](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties)